# Reopening "Is most of the GM-AM Inequality in its codicil?"

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

The [question in question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/is-most-of-the-gm-am-inequality-in-its-codicil-closed) asks whether the AM-GM inequality can be, in some sense, reduced to the case where there is equality. I think this is a reasonable question, and here is a proposed plan for an answer: one could outline a proof for the inequality, in which one brings two variables together, and shows that this decreases the GM without changing the AM; after finitely many such operations, we are left with the case of equality.

The OP also recently asked another [contentious question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/can-x-be-interpreted-as-number-of-customers), which doesn't make much sense to me, and was promptly closed. A possible different course of action, which might be less alienating, is to ask the OP to explain his motives better.

Comment: don't accept the answer yet. I think questions with no accepted answers tend to get more views. `:)` And it is better to click the green check mark after either (a) question is re-opened or (b) the community decides it shouldn't be re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I just want to note that the second question about $\pi(x)$ is **not in fact promptly closed**. As of the writing of this answer there are some close votes on it, but it is still open.

For the first question, I had to look up what *codicil* means in the dictionary. And even after looking it up, I still don't think I understand what the question actually means. On the other hand, your description sounds like a reasonable question. If you edit the question into a way that I understand better, I would voice my support (unfortunately my re-open vote would be also binding, just like my close votes) for a question about "whether the AM-GM inequality can be reduced to the case of the equality".

(Mathematically, I think the answer is yes. But I don't think it is a hundred times easier to prove the AM-GM inequality that way...)